# Asp.Net MVC - Blank model not returning blank data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which a user can fill in x times with the data they want too. The form is posted to the following Action.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Manage(ProductOptionModel DataToAdd)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(DataToAdd);
            }

            var ProdServ = new ProductService();

            if (DataToAdd.ID != 0)
            {
                //Edit Mode.
                DataToAdd = ProdServ.EditProductOption(DataToAdd);
                ViewData["Message"] = "Option Changes Made";

            }else
            {
                //Add
                DataToAdd = ProdServ.AddProductOption(DataToAdd);
                ViewData["Message"] = "New Option Added";
            }

            var RetModel = new ProductOptionModel() {ProductID = DataToAdd.ProductID};
            return View(RetModel);
        }
```

So at the bottom I blank the model (Leaving just the required field) and then return to the view. However the view holds the data from the previously submitted form.

Any ideas why? I have debugged the code and checked that the RetModel variable is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html helpers work this way when a view is returned on HTTP POSTs. They prefer post data over model values.

### Use Post/Redirect/Get

That's why I suggest you use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern that's very well supported in Asp.net MVC. Your controller actions should redirect to some GET action after POST has successfully completed as it is in your case.

```
public ActionResult Process()
{
    return View(new Data { Id = -1 });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(Data data)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(data);
    }
    new MyService().ProcessData(data);
    return RedirectToAction("Process");
}
```

And if you display all previously entered data you can provide those in in the GET action or transfer them from POST to GET action using `TempData` dictionary.

Comment: This approach will work and looks good but, I have a message field (Currently ViewData) that I my need to pass to the user (Telling success,error etc etc) How can i do that using this method since ViewData is lost when RedirectToAction is called.

Comment: Use TempData to send your message. Alternatively you can clear out the model data, using ModelState.Clear(), before you return your View and leave your code as is. But I also prefer the Post/Redirect/Get for a long term solution.

Comment: Validation model state errors are not a problem since they don't redirect as per my code. Success is a different story. I suggest you use `TempData` dictionary as @Jab suggested. `TempData` is there exactly for the purpose of the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. Read about it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the build in input helpers will look at the posted data first and use those values if they exist. Then it will look at the model.